# Merging cells in excel file using java

Tags: java, excel, merge, apache-poi, cell

I am using apache poi to merge multiple headers in excel file. In my excel file I require to merge multiple headers. I am able to merge signle header, but as I need it multiple time, I would have to iterate through it.

When i try to merge the columns with addMergedRegion i got error of intersection. Can anyone help me with this. I want to write headers in first row by merging according to size given in cellsToMerge list.

```
 private void writeheaders(XSSFWorkbook workbook, XSSFSheet sheet, List<String> headers, List<Integer> cellsToMerge, int startRow, int endRow, int startCol) {
 XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(startRow);
 Int endCol=0;

 for(int i=0;i<headers.size();i++){
       If(i==0){
            startCol=0;
            endCol=cellsToMerge.get(i);
       }else{
             startCol=endCol +1;
             endCol = endCol + cellsToMerge.get(i);
       }

      CellRangeAddress region = new CellRangeAddress(startRow, endRow, startCol, endCol) ;
      sheet.addMergedRegion(region);
      Cell cell = row.createCell(startCol);
      cell.setCellValue(headers.get(i));
 }
 }
```